# how to set a new column based on group in pandas

Tags: pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe as follows.

```
   ID  days group
0   1   5.3     A
1   2   6.0     A
2   3   6.7     A
3   4   5.5     B
4   5   6.2     B
5   6   6.4     B
6   7   5.7     B
7   8   7.5     C
8   9   7.2     C
9  10   7.9     C
```

I want to create "group_mean" column that showing mean of days for each group

```
   ID  days group  group_mean
0   1   5.3     A       6.000
1   2   6.0     A       6.000
2   3   6.7     A       6.000
3   4   5.5     B       5.950
4   5   6.2     B       5.000
5   6   6.4     B       5.950
6   7   5.7     B       5.950
7   8   7.5     C       7.533
8   9   7.2     C       7.533
9  10   7.9     C       7.533
```

How can I this?

Comment: `df.groupby('group')['days'].transform('mean')`

Answer (score -1):

```
df['group_mean'] = df.groupby('group')['days'].transform('mean')
```

Comment: code only responses are not recommended and generally down voted. Please provide explanation of your code to help the OP understand what you are trying to do.